# Счетчик в item RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть RecycleView с item разных товаров,в товарах указывается количество товара и цена.Я сделал счетчик в адаптере, при нажатии на кнопку увеличивается или уменьшается количество одного товара и цена соответственно.Но счетчик работает некорректно, а именно:количество товара увеличивается не у одного товара а у всех сразу,и значение цены увеличивается только 1 раз и тоже у всех товаров сразу.

```
    public class MyAdapterProducts extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolderProducts> {
Context c;
ArrayList<Product> products;
String jsonURL2;
int price2, price3;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
public MyAdapterProducts(Context c, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    this.c = c;
    this.products = products;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolderProducts onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model_products, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolderProducts(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolderProducts holder, int position) {
    Product product = products.get(position);
    final String name = product.getName();
    final String anons = product.getAnons();
    final String price = product.getPrice();
    final String product_id = product.getId();
    final String image = product.getImg_url();

    holder.nameTxt.setText(name);
    holder.anonsTxt.setText(anons);
    holder.priceTxt.setText(price + " " + "тг."); //Textview цены
    holder.idTxt.setText(product_id);
    holder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int counter = 1;
           holder.showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter)); //Textview значения счетчика
            price2 = Integer.parseInt(price);
            price3 = Integer.parseInt(price);
            counter++;
            price2 = price2 + price3;
            holder.priceTxt.setText(String.valueOf(price2) + " " + "тг.");
            holder.showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }
    });
    holder.decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int counter = 1;
           // holder.showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

            //counter = count;
            if (counter > 1) {
                counter--;
                price2 = price2 - price3;
                holder.priceTxt.setText(String.valueOf(price2) + " " + "тг.");
                holder.showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: вам нужно сохранять свои значения счетчика в модель (или другое временное хранилище, если эти значения нужны только когда список отображается) для каждой позиции. Затем брать из этой модели, производить манипуляции и записывать новый результат в модель.